# What is meant by “unwholesome words”?

Tags: ephesians, grammatical-historical

> “Let no **unwholesome word** come out of your mouth, but if there is
> any good word for edification according to the need of the moment, say
> that, so that it will give grace to those who hear.” ‭‭Ephesians‬
> ‭4:29‬

**Is the the verse to justify against “cursing” & “swear words” for Christians?  What did Paul mean in this context?  What are unwholesome words defined as?** Is there any historical interpretations here that Paul is using, that maybe don’t apply today?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Paul effectively answers this question of the meaning of "unwholesome talk", or, "corrupting talk", ESV, (Eph 4:29) a few verses later:

> Eph 4:31 - Get rid of all bitterness, rage and anger, outcry and
> slander, along with every form of malice.
>
> Eph 5:4 - Nor should there be obscenity, foolish talk, or crude
> joking, which are out of character, but rather thanksgiving.
>
> Eph 5:6 - Let no one deceive you with empty words, for because of such
> things the wrath of God is coming on the sons of disobedience.

Benson comments on Eph 4:29 as follows:

> The original expression, λογος σαπρος, is literally, rotten or putrid
> speech; that is, speech offensive to the hearers, or calculated to
> infect them with sin; and is in direct opposition to that which is
> seasoned with salt, and is recommended (Colossians 4:6) as tending to
> preserve persons from corruption. The apostle does not merely include
> in this expression obscene discourse of every kind, but also all
> flattery, calumny, railing, boasting, tale-bearing, backbiting,
> commendations of vice and impiety, profane jestings on religion, its
> ministers and professors, trifling conversation; and, indeed, all
> discourse that is not either about necessary business, or, as the next
> clause expresses it, is not good to the use of edifying — Calculated
> to instruct, direct, reprove, encourage, excite to duty, comfort, or
> in some way edify and minister grace to the hearers.

Comment: +1 Interesting, we approached this from two different ways and came up with essentially the same answer.

Comment: Good insight, +1

Answer (score 4):

Basically, σαπρὸς means *smelly* or *rotten*.  In the context it is words that tear down rather than edify.  Thus, it encompasses a huge category.

> σαπρός, ά, όν (...) decayed, rotten.
>
> 1. lit., of spoiled fish ...
> 2. fig. bad, evil, unwholesome ...
>    --
>    Arndt, W., Gingrich, F. W., Danker, F. W., & Bauer, W. (1979). In *A Greek-English lexicon of the New Testament and other early Christian literature : a translation and adaption of the fourth revised and augmented edition of Walter Bauer’s Griechisch-deutsches Worterbuch zu den Schrift en des Neuen Testaments und der ubrigen urchristlichen Literatur* (p. 742). University of Chicago Press.

> σαπρός, † σήπω

> 1. In basic meaning both words relate to the process of “decay.”
>    a. σήπω act. “to cause to decay” ...
>    b. σαπρός “rotting” ... Though what is lit. σαπρόν offends only sight or smell ...
> 2. In the LXX we find
>    a. the act. σήπω once fig. “to destroy” ... b. “of poor quality” ...
> 3. ... decay ...
> 4. ... rotting ...
>    Bauernfeind, O. (1964–). σαπρός, σήπω. In G. Kittel, G. W. Bromiley, & G. Friedrich (Eds.), *Theological dictionary of the New Testament* (electronic ed., Vol. 7, p. 94-97). Eerdmans.

Comment: +1 - I like this answer too.

Comment: Good answer, +1